# Data structure to store integers, floats and text at the same time

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am simulating a DELETE command from SQL in c++. I've tried all the possible data types to temporary store the data from a certain table( a .bin file in my case), but none of them worked.

If I store the entire file at once in a char buffer[5000], the text is safe, but the integers somehow are stored on the address, and in the buffer they look like " }+;-." and so on.

If I select them one by one and concatenate each value to a similar buffer with strncat, and with itoa() if needed, I end up having them perfect but I can't navigate in it using specific data-type size.

I would apreciate very much a suggestion into this. I've literally searched all the internet by now. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you exactly want , but try using a structure. A structure is a type that you define and you can put in it many types like text and int... Then define an array of that structure if you want

Comment: Check out this link on how to use structures: https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/